# Unable to acquire the Redis Lock and the process stuck during the upgrade of Redis servers

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I am testing how my JAVA Application behaves (which connects to Redis for locking mechanism) when I reboot Redis servers from the Redis cluster one at a time. I am using Redisson library to connect to Redis cluster. In the cluster there are 3 servers, all have Sentinels, one server is master and the other two are secondary servers.

When the application runs, it tries to acquire the RLock, perform some task and release the lock. Repeat the process every hour. This runs fine under normal condition.

But when I reboot the Redis servers one at a time, the process in my application stucks at the point where it tries to acquire the lock.

```
isLockFree = redisLock.tryLock(tryAcquireRLockWaitTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I waited for more than 6 hrs but the process never return back. Also I checked the lock key in Redis servers, I could not find the key.
Also, during the reboot I try to read some values from Redis and it works fine.

I even tried the Redisson's tryAsyncLock(tryAcquireRLockWaitTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS), but same issue happened with that as well.

But if I restart my JAVA application after all the Redis servers rebooted, the locking mechanism again runs fine.

So my questions are:
If from the cluster, the Redis servers are getting rebooted one at a time, then why the process is unable to get the lock?
Do I need to restart my application everytime, after there is a reboot to the Redis cluster?

Comment: Do you see any errors in log?

Comment: Nope, I do not see any errors as the process that tries to acquire lock, does not returns

Comment: it might be related to this issue https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/3587 Can you try version attached to this issue?

Comment: Sure, thanks for the suggestion, the redisson version I am currently using is <version>3.12.5</version>.
The version mentioned in above link is 3.15.5, which I do not find under maven repo

Comment: It's hasn't been released yet. Here is the link https://github.com/redisson/redisson/files/6413028/redisson-3.15.5-SNAPSHOT.jar.zip

Comment: Sure Nikita, let me try it.

Comment: Thanks @NikitaKoksharov, this version works